# Как нарисовать окружность на яндекс карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужен конкретный, развернутый пример.

Comment: Яндекс API доступен для нескольких языков программирования - вы про какой конкретно говорите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример работающего кода для АПИ версии 2.
Для версии 1.*, насколько я знаю, окружностей нет.

```
// Создаем круг
myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
// Координаты центра круга
[55.76, 37.60],
// Радиус круга в метрах
15000
]);
// Добавляем круг на карту
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);
```

Comment: а ну гугл картах чтото подобное тоже?

Comment: да фот пример

var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000", //цвет границы

      strokeOpacity: 0.8,     //прозрачность границы

      strokeWeight: 2,        //толщина границы

      fillColor: "#FF0000",   //цвет круга

      fillOpacity: 0.35,      //прозрачность круга

      map: map,               //карта

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
         //центр

      radius: 300             //радиус
    };
    Circle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

Answer (score 2):

```
var circle = new ymaps.geometry.Circle([X, Y], R);
```

Куда уж более развернутый: [geometry.base.Circle](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/geometry.base.Circle.xml).

Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: ладно, а почему тогда код после этой строчки не пашет и круга нетю на карте?

Comment: А что пишет браузер в консоли ошибок?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Circle' of undefined

Comment: package.editor, package.full, package.geoObjects - у вас установлен хотя бы один из этих пакетов? Если нет, установите их. Ошибка вызвана тем, что яваскрипт не может найти объект geometry. Скорее всего, из-за того, что он не установлен.